# Onclick and onchange triggered simultaneously

Tags: javascript, dwr

I have a onChange and onClick events in my code. I expected the onChange needs to execute and then only onClick event will execute.

If I type something in textbox and when I clicks on Button, The alert message shown 1st and the confirmation message also displayed in next. It looks like its becasue of slow processing in DWR. Did anyone have solution for this.

```
 function ChangingEvent()
 {
     //Here I have a dwr function to fetch data from DB and checks for Duplicate.
   if(Duplicate)
      confirm('Are you sure want to allow Duplicate');
 }

 function ClickEvent()
 {
    //Here Some validation part and submitting the form
    if(field1.value=="")
      alert('field 1 is null');
    form.submit();
 }

 <input type="text" onChange=ChangingEvent()>
 <input type="button" onClick=ClickEvent()>
```

Comment: `function` should be lowercase

Comment: How is this running without quotes around the argument to `confirm()`?

Comment: The `confirm` message isn't displayed until the asynchronous call to the database completes, so the alert runs first.

Comment: HI barmar, Thanks for your reply. It is just a sample code. So pls ignore the errors here.  Do you have any solution for this.

Comment: How about doing the validation in `ChangingEvent` instead of `ClickEvent`?

Comment: U could set a parameter that is true or false that you set in the `ChangeingEvent` that you can check in the `ClickEvent`, so not to trigger that validation if set to true. Also you can also set a class on the input that say processing, and pressing the button, if any input has that class return false with a message.